# VBscript to export total row count to another csv with the ability to add a custom name

Tags: vbscript

I am using the following VBscript to get the total row count from my csv files. I need help in exporting the returned line count to a csv which will have two columns Name and Count name will be anything and the count is the returned count.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
myFile = objArgs(0)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(myFile,1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfLine
line = objFile.Line
objFile.ReadLine
Loop
WScript.Echo "Line count of", myFile , "is", line
```

The way i would like to call the script would be:

```
Cscript 'vbscript_name' file_name_to_count 'custom_name' 'export_count.csv'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I not see where is the break, as you only need to create new file and write just 2 lines in, but it w'd be something like this:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objArgs(2), 2, True)
objFile.WriteLine "Name,Count"
objFile.WriteLine objArgs(1) & "," & line
objFile.Close
```

And just to become more friendly, here is the whole deal:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
iLinesCount = FileLinesCount(objArgs(0))
DumpResult objArgs(2), objArgs(1), iLinesCount
WScript.Echo "File: " & objArgs(0) & " has " & iLinesCount & " lines"

Function FileLinesCount(strFileName)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        With .OpenTextFile(strFileName, 1)
            Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                Call .ReadLine
            Loop
            FileLinesCount = .Line
        End With
    End With
End Function

Sub DumpResult(strFileName, strCustomName, iCount)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        With .OpenTextFile(strFileName, 2, True)
            .WriteLine "Name,Count"
            .WriteLine strCustomName & "," & iCount
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Also it's good to add error checks for your command line arguments, but I live this simple task to you, cheers!

P.S. I suppose you'll prefer to append your count data to existing file instead of creating new file for each counted source file. If so, you have a very little work on `DumpResult` function, just need to open the file for appending (`ForAppending` = 8) and add "header" (column names) only then needs (i.e. when the file is newly created):

```
' modified version w`d be:
Sub DumpResult(strFileName, strCustomName, iCount)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        With .OpenTextFile(strFileName, 8, True)
            If .Line = 1 Then ' new empty file
                .WriteLine "Name,Count" ' add column names
            End If
            .WriteLine strCustomName & "," & iCount
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Panayot, This kind of works but the output varies from being 2 lines more from the actual output to 3 times more then what was in the actual csv file. Any ideas??? Thanks

Comment: @user1967987 Hmm, very strange, I can`t imagine a reason this to happens.